# A multicategory is a ... with one object?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, enriched-category-theory, profunctors

We all know that

> A monoidal category is a bicategory with one object.

How do we fill in the blank in the following sentence?

> A multicategory is a ... with one object.

The answer is fairly clear: it'll be a bit like a bicategory, but instead of being able to compose $1$-cells straightforwardly, all we can do is specify, for any 'composable' sequence
$$
A_0 \xrightarrow{f_1} \cdots \xrightarrow{f_n} A_n\,,
$$
of $1$-cells and any $1$-cell $g \colon A_0 \to A_n$, the set of $2$-cells
$$
f_1,\dots,f_n \Rightarrow g\,.
$$
What is the name of such a thing?  A natural example, for a given SMCC $\mathcal V$, has $\mathcal V$-enriched categories as the objects, profunctors $\mathcal C^{op}\otimes \mathcal C\to \mathcal V$ as the $1$-cells and, for any collection
$$
\mathcal C_0,\cdots,\mathcal C_n
$$
of categories and profunctors $F_i\colon \mathcal C_{i-1}^{op}\otimes \mathcal C_i\to \mathcal V$, $G\colon \mathcal C_0^{op}\otimes \mathcal C_n \to \mathcal V$, the set of extranatural transformations
$$
\phi_{b_1,\cdots,b_{n-1}} \colon F_0(a,b_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes F_n(b_{n-1},c)\Rightarrow G(a,c)
$$
as the $2$-cells $F_1,\cdots,F_n \Rightarrow G$.

Of course, if $\mathcal V$ is cocomplete, then this is equivalent to the usual bicategory of $\mathcal V$-enriched profunctors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has been called a "fc-multicategory" by Tom Leinster, for example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903004).

I think this as also been called a "Hypervirtual double category" [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04070.pdf), but I don't remember if this is exactly the same notion or if there are some additional assumption in the second link.

Comment: fc-multicategories seem to generalize what I'm talking about slightly, by allowing vertical $1$-cells between objects as well.  I suppose that that is a natural generalization: for example, in the profunctor case we can take the vertical $1$-cells to be the ordinary functors.

Comment: Oh, yes you are write I missed that: the structure you are considering is a fc-multicategory with only identity vertical 1-cells.

Comment: Shulman and Cruttwell have been using the term "virtual double categories" for fc-multicategories. Hypervirtual double categories generalise these by also including cells with empty horizontal targets (besides the usual target: a single horizontal morphism).

It looks like that, when restricting to a single identity as the set of vertical morphisms, a hypervirtual double category consists of a multicategory C equipped with a module C -|-> 1, in the sense of 2.3.6 of [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305049), where 1 is the terminal multicategory.

Comment: This is interesting, it makes me wonder if there is a similar characterisation of general hypervirtual double categories.

Comment: [Here's](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2460) the paper where Cruttwell and Shulman introduced the "virtual" terminology. "A unified framework for generalized multicategories"

Comment: Name of first 'here':  [Leinster - fc-multicategories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903004).  Name of second 'here':  [Koudenburg - A double-dimensional approach to formal category theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04070).

Answer (score 10):

Another established structure very close to what you want is **opetopic bicategories**, which are equivalent to classical bicategories but formulated opetopically; see e.g. §3 of [Cheng 2003, *Opetopic bicategories: comparison with the classical theory*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304285.pdf), and the subsection *Non-algebraic notions of bicategory* at the end of §3.4 of [Leinster 2003, *Higher operads, higher categories*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305049.pdf).

Concretely, in an opetopic bicategory $B$, you have a graph of 0-cells and 1-cells like in a normal bicategory; the source of a 2-cell is not just a 1-cell but a composable string of 1-cells; 2-cell composition looks just like what you’d expect; and the 1-cell composition condition says that for every composable sequence of 1-cells, there’s a *universal* 2-cell out of them, for a certain sense of universality.

Keeping all of this except the last condition — call such a thing an **opetopic bicategories minus 1-cell composition** — seems to give exactly what you’re asking for.  In the one-object case, the 1-cell composition condition is exactly what Leinster calls *representability* of a multicategory (Def 3.3.1, [ibid.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305049.pdf)) — so adding this back recovers the equivalence between monoidal categories and one-object bicategories:

(monoidal category) = (multicategory with representability) = (one-object opetopic bicategory minus 1-cell composition, with 1-cell composition) = (one-object opetopic bicategory) = (one-object bicategory)

Comparing this with Simon Henry’s answer, I would expect (opetopic bicategories minus 1-cell composition) should be fairly concretely equivalent to (fc-multicategories with only identity vertical 1-cells); indeed, Leinster hints at such a connection in the subsection mentioned above, though he doesn’t spell it out precisely.

Answer (score 6):

I think it worth mentioning that precisely the notion described in the question is given in Cockett–Koslowski–Seely's [Morphisms and modules for poly-bicategories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/11/2/11-02abs.html), where it is called a *multi-bicategory*. A one-object multi-bicategory is a multicategory. As noted in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320646/a-multicategory-is-a-with-one-object/320697#comment799346_320650) for Simon Henry's answer, Leinster's fc-multicategories are strictly more general: they are to multi-bicategories what pseudo-double categories are to bicategories. A multi-bicategory is precisely an fc-multicategory whose vertical cells are all identities.